# HashiCorp Vault No handler for route error despite secrets engine being enabled through the UI

Tags: security, hashicorp-vault

Using the non-dev vault server, I went ahead and used “Enable new engine” in the UI for kv version 1 and created a secret.

As a test, I am using a token with root permissions to attempt the following and receive the no route error:

curl -H "X-Vault-Token: " -X GET https://vaultwebsite.com/v1/secret/kvtest1/test12/test123

{“errors”:[“no handler for route ‘secret/kvtest/anothertest/test’”]}

My understanding is that there shouldn’t be the no handler issue as I enabled that secrets engine through the UI. Am I missing a step, policy, or is this an API path issue?

One of my references was https://www.reddit.com/r/hashicorp/comments/c429fo/simple_vault_workflow_help/ which lead me to review the enabled amount.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

My guess is that you've enabled a KV engine and wrote a secret to it, but the path `secret/` is wrong.

For example, if i enable an engine and then try to read an existing value, then it works

```
$ vault secrets enable -version=1 -path kv kv
Success! Enabled the kv secrets engine at: kv/
$ curl --header "X-Vault-Token: $VAULT_TOKEN" $VAULT_ADDR/v1/kv/foo
{"request_id":"2db249af-10de-01c5-4603-8f89a46897b5","lease_id":"","renewable":false,"lease_duration":2764800,"data":{"v6":"1"},"wrap_info":null,"warnings":null,"auth":null}
```

But if i now try to read from a non existing path, i'd get the same error as you, for example

```
$ curl --header "X-Vault-Token: $VAULT_TOKEN" $VAULT_ADDR/v1/foobar/foo
{"errors":["no handler for route 'foobar/foo'"]}
```

It would help if you list your existing mounts and verify the path

```
$ curl --header "X-Vault-Token: $VAULT_TOKEN" $VAULT_ADDR/v1/sys/mounts
# or
$ vault secrets list
```

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error when I was trying to access to a wrong path. For example, I enabled the ldap engine with specific path `-path=ssh-client-signer`

```
vault secrets enable -path=ssh-client-signer ssh
```

So the actual url for ssh sign should be `ssh-client-signer/roles`, no `ssh/roles`

```
curl \
     --header "X-Vault-Token: ......" \
     --request LIST \
     http://vault:8200/v1/ssh-client-signer/roles
```